# Link invertase/react-native-firebase without CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, linker

So I've tried to follow this

http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/setting-up-firebase-without-cocoapods/
And then this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

Firebase SDK seems to be loaded, XCode says:

> 2017-06-18 19:35:49.969 myapp[2224] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not
>   currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more
>   at *(stackoverflow forbids shorteners)*
>
> 2017-06-18 19:35:49.971 myapp[2224] 
>   [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.4001000 started

Then I'm getting a "Native module cannot be null" red screen after React Native loads.

XCode says:

> 2017-06-18 19:48:39.975 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:184]
>   Initializing  (parent: , executor: (null))
>
> 2017-06-18 19:48:39.980 [warn][tid:main][RCTBridge.m:114] Class
>   RCTCxxModule was not exported. Did you forget to use
>   RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
>
> 2017-06-18 19:48:39.994 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:302] Running
>   application myapp ({
>       initialProps = {
>       };
>       rootTag = 1; })
>
> 2017-06-18 19:48:40.305 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript]
>   Native module cannot be null.

Did anyone have better luck than me?